# Footable rows do not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web2py, footable

Columns display correctly in footable but rows do not show up. I see that data is correctly coming in as the paging shows right number of pages according to the number of rows, but the rows do not show up. This [page](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/644) correctly shows my problem. But the solution mentioned in the comments did not work for me. Following are my code snippets:

Header:

```
    <!--Footable https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-footable -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--JS package CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--JS packages-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--Footable https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-footable -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.filtering.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.4/footable.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.4/footable.bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<div id = "example_class" style="margin-left: 17rem; margin-top:2rem">
   <table id="example" class="data-table" data-paging="true"></table>
</div>

<script>
var ft_init_options = {
            columns: {{=XML(columns)}},
            rows: {{=XML(rows)}},
            paging: {
                enabled: true
            }
        };
        var ft = FooTable.init('#example', ft_init_options);
</script>
```

As mentioned in the above link, it could be the order of the files that are included in the page. But I could not get it right. Kindly help!
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
    <!--Footable https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-footable -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.core.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--JS package CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   
    {{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}

    <!--JS packages-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--Footable https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-footable -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.1.6/footable.filtering.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--chart-->
    <script charset="utf-8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/3.0.9/highcharts.js"></script>
```